# How to Call ATL Error() in a normal cpp

Tags: com

I'm trying to call Error("My Test") in normal cpp class (Not a COM object, but this class will be used by COM). In the compilation, I get error saying

'Error': identifier not found

I have included #include  in the cpp file. Please explain why it does not work.

NOTE: I can use Error() inside COM object successfully

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Error()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a9x7e4(VS.80).aspx) is a static member function of `CComCoClass`. You could call it directly, but you would need to provide the template parameters which is not very convenient. Instead you can call [`AtlReportError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3hhtydd(VS.80).aspx) which is what `Error()` does internally.